# Comparing effect of two IVs

Tags: regression, econometrics, linear-model, linear

I use a linear regression model to understand the effects of two regressors $X$ and $Y$ on a dependent variable $Z$. Let us assume that a unit change in $X$ and $Y$ are comparably interpretable. I now want to compare the relative impact of a unit change of $X$ versus $Y$ on $Z$. How do I perform an appropriate statistical test on the coefficients $\beta_X$ and $\beta_Y$ corresponding to the two regressors in order to claim that the effect of $X$ on $Z$ is greater than that of $Y$ or vice versa? Is it true that if and only if $\beta_X > \beta_Y$ and both are sufficiently significant, we can say that $X$ has a greater effect on $Z$ than $Y$?

Comment: Can you clarify why you wouldn't just compare the coefficients (or the std error around coefficients)? This would give you the straightfwd interpretation of 'a 1 unit increase in x results in a greater chg in z than a 1 unit increase in Y'.

Comment: If the units and scales for X and Y are very different, you can normalize both from 0 to 100 and then perform the regression - this would tell you the the effect of  *percentage* changes in each on the value of Z.

Comment: @James That's not so, because normalization to 0..100 does not (generally) correspond to percentage changes in the original units. For instance, if the range of X originally goes from 100 to 200, then each unit difference in the normalized scale corresponds to *variable* relative changes ranging from 1/100 = 1% to 1/200 = 0.5% on the original scale. Esperanto: you must tell us exactly what *you* mean by "greater than," because there are many possible interpretations of the "size of effect" of a variable on a dependent variable. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+strength

Comment: Thank you all for useful inputs, I have edited the question to make it a bit more precise? My confusion is arising from whether one coefficient being greater than the other along with both coefficients being sufficiently significant is necessary to make such a claim?

Comment: @whuber, you raise a good point. How then to handle data that ranges from -200 to 200? I would still rescale this from 0 to 100 to determine percentage change, what would you recommend?

Comment: @James You will need to decide what a "percentage change" might mean relative to a starting value that could be (a) negative or even (b) zero.  Regardless, normalizing the values is not going to help.

Comment: @whuber for a statistician of your caliber this is trivially obvious. For some of the people I have presented to in business meetings, without scaling from 0 to 100 they would be unable to understand without at least an hour of side discussion - maybe two.